# JavaScript function returns false when wrapped in .then() method an true when outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently trying to extend the Sir Trevor Content Editor to prevent it from using a JavaScript prompt to obtain a URL/hyperlink highlighted text and to use a custom dialog I have created. The modal window I have created has a text input which returns a valid href (which is a string), the modal window closes and passes the value back as desired... everything seems to be returned and working well however my modified code doesn't work, here's my code

```
// overwrite the prompt provided by Sir Trev Link.onClick
SirTrevor.Formatters.Link.onClick = function() {

    // this is my code
    var thisCMD = this.cmd;

    modalService.prompt(Label.for.textinput.from.jsonfile).result.then(function(href) {
        document.execCommand(thisCMD, false, href);
    });

    /*
    // This is the original code!
    var link = prompt(i18n.t("general:link")),
        link_regex = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/.)|mailto(?=\:[-\.\w]+@)/;

    if(link && link.length > 0) {

        if(!link_regex.test(link)) {
            link = "http://" + link;
        }

        document.execCommand(this.cmd, false, link);
    } 
    */
}
```

;

Now the `href` I return is valid and not null, the `thisCMD` variable I create and pass has the correct value and the correct type (the same as the original this.cmd). Everything should work however I have noticed the following when testing the original and modified `document.execCommand()`

```
// original
console.log(document.execCommand(this.cmd, false, link)); // returns true

// modified / extended code
console.log(document.execCommand(thisCMD, false, href)); // returns false
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on how I can fix this or tell me where I'm going wrong? My app is written using AngularJS

**UPDATE**

Just to assist this is the whole Sir Trevor function that I am trying to partially modify, notice the `OnClick` method

```
var Link = SirTrevor.Formatter.extend({


  title: "link",
  iconName: "link",
  cmd: "CreateLink",
  text : "link",

  onClick: function() {

    var link = prompt(i18n.t("general:link")),
        link_regex = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/.)|mailto(?=\:[-\.\w]+@)/;

    if(link && link.length > 0) {

     if (!link_regex.test(link)) {
       link = "http://" + link;
     }

     document.execCommand(this.cmd, false, link);
    }
  },

  isActive: function() {
    var selection = window.getSelection(),
        node;

    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
      node = selection.getRangeAt(0)
                      .startContainer
                      .parentNode;
    }

    return (node && node.nodeName == "A");
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that `document.execCommand` must be triggered by a user action, i.e. it works only when called in an event handler?

Comment: Yes it is possible as the original code is wired up to a prompt, the function is used to perform Rich-Text Edit action

Comment: I don't know that it answers your question, but it looks as though you're taking a synchronous call and trying to make it asynchronous.  It wouldn't be terribly surprising if that were to fail.  But I don't have any particular suggestion about that.  I would be curious as to what `this` referred to in both cases during `execCommand`, and if that made any difference.  But that's simply a dim suspicion.

Comment: I will increase the original code to answer what "this" is

Comment: While that's interesting, I was wondering more about the run-time type of `this`, especially when your promise is being resolved.  I thought that there was some chance that that might affect the behavior of `document.execCommand`, but the more I think about it, the less I can see a reason for that suspicion.

Comment: I think the reason has to do with the prompt being blocking and the promise being async?

Comment: Actually I think it is because the model takes the window focus whilst the prompt doesn't take the prompt away from the highlighted text!